# Unwrap Struct Once And Modify Multiple Values

Tags: rust, mapping, unwrap, rust-ink

I have the following code:

```
((&self.items).get(&self.lastIndex)).unwrap().val1 = "hello";
((&self.items).get(&self.lastIndex)).unwrap().val2 = "world";
```

Map of ink storage. How can I unwrap the struct from KV once and modify all values at once? Like so:

```
/// not rust syntax
((&self.items).get(&self.lastIndex))
.unwrap()->{
  this.val1 = "";
  this.val2 = "";
}
```

Comment: You can't `get(...).value = ...`. `get()` returns a shared, immutable reference.

Comment: What is the problem with assigning the result to a variable and then mutating it? Like `let item = self.items.get_mut(&self.last_index).unwrap(); item.val1 = "hello"; item.val2 = "world";`?